# Which class of functions are quite complicated in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, optimization

Deep learning is a field in which we need neural networks that are deep enough to carry on our task. The important fucntions in deep neural networks can be classified in to three classes: activation function, neural network function and loss function.

Activation functions are a part of neural network function and neural network functions may be a part of loss functions.

Consider the following paragraphs from [Numerical Computation](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html) of a deep learning book

> Optimization algorithms that use only the gradient, such as gradient
> descent, are called ﬁrst-order optimization algorithms. Optimization
> algorithms that also use the Hessian matrix, such as Newton’s method,
> are called second-order optimization algorithms (Nocedal and Wright,
> 2006).
>
> The optimization algorithms employed in most contexts in this book are
> applicable to a wide variety of functions but come with almost no
> guarantees. Deep learning algorithms tend to lack guarantees because
> the **family of functions used in deep learning is quite complicated.** In
> many other ﬁelds, the dominant approach to optimization is to design
> optimization algorithms for a limited family of functions.

The last passage is talking about the family of functions used in deep learning. Which class of functions, among the three I mentioned, they are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

From the phrasing, it seems that complicated refers to the non-convexity of the loss landscapes of neural networks. We do not have formal guarantees of convergence in general for such landscapes. This non-convexity is a property of both the function defined by the neural network, and the particular loss function we use.

In practice though, **non-convexity stems from the non-linear activation functions** as we almost exclusively use cross-entropy loss when training neural networks.